# having a problem offline install tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I am using Python 3.6 from Anaconda 4.3.1 on Windows 10. I'm trying to offline install TensorFlow， and i have download a .whl file to install module.
[install tensorflow warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRlGY.jpg)

But I have installed the tensorboard 1.12 moudule on my computer. 
[I have installed the tensorboard moudule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6IPl.jpg)

I have no way to install tensorflow now. please help me， thanks！

Comment: You are online to post this-- why don't you stay online and install TensorFlow online?

Comment: Because our office computer can‘t connect to the Internet for data security.  ：（

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Tensorflow 1.11 need tensorboard version 1.11, but I have installed tensorboard 1.12.